# How can i use printf in java to to print formatted output

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I'm trying to format my output with *`System.out.printf();`* function in java .
the output format is like this :

In each line of output there should be two columns: 
The first column contains the String and is left justified using exactly  characters. 
The second column contains the integer, expressed in exactly  digits; if the original input has less than three digits, you must pad your output's leading digits with zeroes. 

================================
java                                 100 
cpp                                     065 
python                         050 

================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String's [format](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) to format strings the way "sprintf" does in C.

From that reference, adapting to your need:

- Padding left with zeros:

  ```
  String.format("|%03d|", 93); // prints: |093|
  ```
- String of spefiied length (involves max and min)

  ```
  String.format("|%-15.15s|", "Hello World"); |Hello World   |
  ```

  You want left justified so "-N" instead of N for first value

Java 8's official format reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

And format string documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax